# Sync files in the documents directory across devices

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I've added the capability of adding images to an existing which uses CoreData and CloudKit to save and sync data across devices.
Since images are large in size, I store images in the documents directory and save the file name in CoreData.

```
// "imgData" is the jpeg data of the image 


// create a unique name for the file
let date1 = String( Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate )
let imageName = date1.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "-") + ".jpeg"

// get the path to the documents directory
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!


do {
    let filePath = path.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    try imgData.write(to: filePath) // save image data to documents directory

} catch {
   ......
}


// then I store the "imageName" to CoreData
let newRecord = EntityName(context: moc)
newRecord.imgName = imageName
.....

do {
    try self.moc.save()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Then I use following code to display images (in SwiftUI) from the saved image name.

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: path.appendingPathComponent(entityName.imgName!).path) ?? UIImage())
```

The app can get all the data (including the file names of images) from iCloud when I delete and reinstalled the app or when I install the app on another device.
But all the image data is gone.

So how can I sync all the files in the documents directory across devices like CloudKit syncs data across devices.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to save images in the iCloud Drive.

[Follow the instructions of this article](https://dev.to/nemecek_f/ios-saving-files-into-user-s-icloud-drive-using-filemanager-4kpm)

then (after following the instructions the above article), change the path of the documents directory by replace this

> // get the path to the documents directory 
> `let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!`

with this
`let path = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")!`

That's it. Super simple.